# schema.org: aggregateRating different notations

Tags: schema.org

I found different notations for aggregateRating on the internet.

Can somebody please explain the difference between the following two?

**Notation 1**

```
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
```

**Notation 2**

```
<span property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation 1 is using the Microdata format, while Notation 2 is using RDFa Lite. You should pick one format for any entities you are marking up. JSON-LD is another format option.

What you mark up, like aggregateRating, is part of the vocabulary you are using. In this case from schema.org.